# urllib.request: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object

Tags: python, urllib

I need to access an HTML website and search that website for images. It might not be that pretty, but I am able to access the website, I just need some guidance on the best way to search for the IMG's.

I tried to treat it like a file but I am getting an error saying I need to convert the data to bytes.

Let me know what you think.

```
    from urllib import request
    import re

    website = request.urlopen('https://www.google.com', "rb")
    html = website.read()
    hand = html.decode("UTF-8")
    for line in hand:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if re.search('^img', line):
            print(line)
```

> TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file
>   object. It cannot be of type str

I expected to get a list of imgs

Comment: The search `re.search('^img', line)` is not likely to get you anywhere.  That's only going to match the chars 'img' if they appear at the beginning of the line, which for HTML, they never will. - I see other things that I don't think will work either - can you use any python packages that you want, or are you restricted to just using the standard python library?

Comment: @Steve Yes, I think I should try and stick to the standard Python library, reached out to the professor regarding this question, no response.   Although, how would you solve this issue while using a different library? It may not be able to help me on this issue, but could help me solve future problems.

Comment: So are you further along?  Have you resolved the initial problem so you are now getting back HTML?  I hope so.  I can help you move forward from there.  Here are some other things I see: 1) you don't need to decode the incoming HTML.  That `html.decode()` line should not be necessary, and may just fail.  2) `for line in hand:` isn't going to work because `hand` (or `html`) is a string, and you can't loop through lines in a string that way.  Usually, when using regular expressions, you just operate on the whole piece of text rather than breaking it into lines.

Comment: I asked about other libraries because there are libraries that help you parse HTML.  The most common one, from what I've seen, is BeautifulSoup.  If you can't use that, and must use regular expressions, that's fine.  But you should get to a point that you have a string with the full HTML document in it, and then we can go from there with working on your regular expression skills (assuming regular expressions are the right way to go for parsing the HTML).

Comment: Thanks all, I was able to access the web page. I need to search for images now, but that is a new post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It might not be that pretty, but I am able to access the website..

Actually, given that the error is coming from calling the function that accesses the website, you are not able to access the website.

You need to have a look at the function signature of [`urllib.request.urlopen()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen).

```
urllib.request.urlopen(url, data=None, [timeout, ]*, cafile=None, capath=None, cadefault=False, context=None)
```

In this line of your code:

```
website = request.urlopen('https://www.google.com', "rb")
```

... the string `'rb'` is being interpreted as the `data` parameter to be sent in the body of your request. This is because you have provided 2 positional arguments of which `'rb'` is the second, and `data` is the second positional argument in the function signature.

This is what `data` is allowed to be:

> The supported object types include bytes, file-like objects, and iterables.

So the string `'rb'` is not any of those types.

But the real issue here is that you are guessing how to use the function. The `open()` built in function and the `urllib.request.urlopen()` function are very different in how they operate and as such you need to read the documentation to know how to use them properly.

Also, I'd like to suggest that unless you absolutely have to use `urllib`, use the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library instead.

Comment: So I went back to the drawing board to start over with something more simple in order to understand what I am working with.                                                     ```import urllib.request```                                                                                      ```import re```
```import ssl```       

    ```website = 'https://www.google.com'```
    ```html = urllib.request.urlopen(website)```
    ```for line in html:```
     ``` #line = line.rstrip()```
     ``` print(line)``` I hope this was clear enough to understand.

Comment: If you have been able to resolve the `TypeError` then you should mark this question as resolved and ask a new question specific to the issues that you are now experiencing. Making this question a convolution of your further issues will not be beneficial to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of [function](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.request.html) `urlopen` is:

```
urllib.request.urlopen(url, data=None, [timeout, ]*, cafile=None, capath=None, cadefault=False, context=None)
```

In your code, `urlopen('https://www.google.com', "rb")` setting "rb" string to `data` argument, not `mode` argument in another function `open`.